# Common Project .Net Build in Docker

Tags: asp.net, .net, docker

I have multiple microservices that have a common dependency. This common dep is not really small and takes a bit of time to build on it's own.

Since each microservice has it's own "dotnet publish" step the common project is getting build multiple times.

I have isolated the "dotnet restore" beforehand and this does not cause any issues and sped up the build time across all of the microservices due to caching already. I would like to try the same with the "dotnet publish".

```
FROM somebase:1.0 AS base
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0.201-bullseye-slim AS dotnet-prep
COPY . ./src/
RUN mkdir ./proj && cd ./src && \
  find . -type f -a \( -iname "*.sln" -o -iname "*.csproj" \) \
    -exec cp --parents "{}" ../proj/ \;

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0.201-bullseye-slim AS dotnet-restore
WORKDIR /src
COPY --from=dotnet-prep ./proj .
RUN dotnet restore /ignoreprojectextensions:.dcproj

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0.201-bullseye-slim AS dotnet-common-build
COPY --from=dotnet-restore ./root/.nuget ./root/.nuget
COPY --from=dotnet-restore ./src ./src/
COPY --from=dotnet-prep ./src ./src/
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet build "/src/MySolution.Common/MySolution.Common/MySolution.Common.csproj" -c ${BUILD_CONFIGURATION}

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0.201-bullseye-slim AS dotnet-publish
COPY --from=dotnet-restore ./root/.nuget ./root/.nuget
COPY --from=dotnet-restore ./src ./src/
COPY --from=dotnet-common-build ./src ./src/
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "/src/MySolution.Core/Export/MySolution.Core.Export.API/MySolution.Core.Export.API.csproj" -c ${BUILD_CONFIGURATION} -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
COPY --from=dotnet-publish /app/publish .
RUN apt update && apt-get install -y libgdiplus libc6-dev && ln -s /usr/lib/libgdiplus.so /usr/lib/gdiplus.dll
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MySolution.Core.Export.API.dll"]
```

Sadly this is not helping and the publish step is building the common project again.